# aws s3 sync - how to exclude only certain files from being deleted from s3 during a sync even if they dont exist on local

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Here is the situation:

I have a folder containing 5 files in my local repository:
folder/fileA
folder/fileB
folder/fileC
folder/fileD
folder/fileE

And I have the same 5 files on the s3 bucket: myBucketName. The local repository and the aws s3 bucket are in sync. What I want to accomplish is this:

1. If I add any file manually to the s3 bucket and NOT locally, I DO NOT want this file to be deleted from S3 upon sync.
2. If I delete any file from S3, I DO NOT WANT that file to be deleted from local.
3. If I add a file to my local repository, I want the sync to add the file to S3 via the sync.
4. If I delete a file from my local repository, I want it to be deleted from S3 via the sync.

So I now add the following to aws s3 myBucketName:

folderB/fileA
folderB/fileB
folderB/fileC
folderB/fileD
folderB/fileE

If I do sync now, it recognizes that folderB/* exists on s3 but not on local so it deletes it from s3. I DO NOT WANT this behavior. So essentially I want the sync to happen but ignore the delete operation for folderB/*

Is there a way for me to accomplish all 4 scenarios using one aws s3 sync command?

Currently this is what I have:

aws s3 sync localDirectory s3://myBucketName/ 
--delete 
--exclude ".*" \

What should I change this to to accomplish the above scenarios?

Comment: Two commands, always in this sequence: 1) sync S3 to local without the `---delete` flag and 2) sync local to S3 with the `--delete` flag?

Answer (score 0):

Requirements #1 and #4 compete against each other.

The `aws s3 sync` command does not keep a history of files -- it can only look at what is in the source and destination and make a decision.

In #1, you want a file added to S3 (but not locally) to be kept and not deleted.

However, in #4, you want a file deleted from local to be kept in S3 and not deleted from S3.

The problem is that the AWS CLI cannot see the difference between these two situations. All it sees is that there is a file in S3 that is not in local. To satisfy #4, it would need the `--delete` parameter. However, this would also delete any object in S3 that is not also in local since the AWS CLI doesn't know when/where files were created. It just looks at the current situation and would delete any file in the target that is not in the destination.

You would need to provide another way to identify which files to delete or not delete, such as putting them in different directories and not syncing those directories.

Comment: So is there a way to exclude only certain files from being deleted from S3? I  want the --delete flag to be there, but For certain files, I want them to be excluded from the S3 delete.

ex:
If I have added FolderB/fileA, FolderB/fileB, FolderB/fileC to s3, but not on local, I want FolderB/* to be excluded from the delete functionality. But for all files which are on both my local and S3. I want the normal --delete functionalty

Comment: You might be able to `--exclude` certain directories, but you'll need to experiment. See: [Use of Exclude and Include Filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters)

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that there are currently no logical operators between --include and --exclude so it will just sync with specified arguments sequentially.

I ran: `aws s3 sync --include="dt=202205*" --exclude="dt=20220530" s3://path_to_bucket/folder`
and it still copied all files for `20220530`. Probably worth raising a ticket with aws.